# Extract Path from Href link using Jmeter

Tags: regex, httprequest, jmeter, href

I am trying to develop a simple test script using Jmeter that can do a bing search and randomly select a link from search results and navigate into the selected link. I am able to capture and randomize the link selection using Regex Extractor & Random variable functions but what I am not sure is, how to go about extracting the path from randomly captured href link.i.e., if the captured link is "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework", I want to extract "/wiki/.NET_Framework" from the link and substitute it in the "Path" textspace of the subsequent HTTP requests. If I am correct, I think using Regex Extractor is not possible here as there are no unique boundaries inorder to extract the path directly from response of the page .

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework` into components:

- `http` - **protocol**
- `en.wikipedia.org` - **host**
- `/wiki/.NET_Framework` - **path**

Add [Beanshell Pre Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of the request, where you need to substitute path and add the following code to Script area:

```
import java.net.URL;

URL url = new URL(vars.get("LINK"));
sampler.setProtocol(url.getProtocol());
sampler.setDomain(url.getHost());
sampler.setPath(url.getPath());
```

The code above assumes that Reference name for your URL is "LINK". Change it to the reference name which is specified in Regular Expression Extractor and it should work fine.

Beanshell Pre Processor is executed before request so all necessary fields will be populated.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details on Beanshell scripting.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my query. The code you suggested works and solved my issue..But I am facing another minor issue now..with the help of log.info() function, i found that vars.get("LINK") seems to be returning the complete dynamically captured href link along with "nullnull" words appended to the end of href link..what could be the reason for this? This is how it looks, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_netnullnull

Comment: I need to see response and your regular expression/template to answer, it's quite hard to say what's wrong with your regex

Comment: Apologies for taking your time.. I resolved it myself. thanks for pointing towards Regex,  I had committed a mistake in template attribute of Regex, I had wrote it as $1$$2$$3$. It worked perfectly fine after deleting $2$$3$. Sorry again for taking your time.